# AWS Dns record A not navigate to elb

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have a domain on aws, I have created a certificate with success
I have a A record on hosted zone pointing to my ELB dns
when using the ELB url - the website load unsecure.
when using the domain the website wont even load.
when I check ns lookup on my domain name it bring up IP this ip show my website
How can I fix the navigate from my domain to the website ?

Comment: Couple of things to confirm? 1) Do you have an HTTPS listener on your ELB and using this certificate? 2) Did you created an A record towards you ELB DNS using "ALIAS" option? 3) What does output of curl command "curl -lv http://<domain>" gives you?